# Gatsby and Netlify CMS Image Widget: Is it possible to use an image or a url string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I'm using Gatsby and Netlify CMS for an image upload. I'm using the image widget and when I upload an image to the media library, my Gatsby site works fine. However, if I change the image to a URL string of an existing image, my Gatsby page query breaks:

```
      Field "featureImage" must not have a selection since type "String" has no
subfields.
```

I suspect this is obviously because my graphQL query was set up to expect an image file, and I've changed that file to a string in the CMS. Is there a way to make this implementation dynamic? Here's the relevant code:

PAGE QUERY IN TEMPLATE COMPONENT

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexPageTemplate {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { templateKey: { eq: "index-page" } }) {
      frontmatter {
        featureImage {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 2048, quality: 100) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
        instagram
        twitter
        facebook
        email
      }
    }
  }
`
```

GATSBY NODE FOR RELATIVE PATH IMAGES

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  fmImagesToRelative(node) // convert image paths for gatsby images

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value,
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lack of details in the answer since it's a very general issue and needs debugging. My 2 cents:

- Check the path of the filesystem in your `gatsby-node.js`: Gatsby needs to know where are those assets stored in your project in order to create the proper GraphQL nodes using its transformers and sharps. For example:

  ```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `uploads`,
        path: `${__dirname}/static/assets/images`
      }
    },
  ```
- Check the paths, naming, extensions of everything involved (images, folders, etc).
- Check your `media_folder` and `public_folder` folder. They should look like:

  ```
    media_folder: static/assets/images
    public_folder: /assets/images
  ```

  Notice the missing slash in `media_folder` at the beginning.
- Check the plugin's order. All your filesystem needs to be set above the remark plugins.
- Use [`gatsby-remark-relative-images-v2`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-relative-images-v2/) to create relative paths for assets:

  ```
    resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    options: {
      plugins: [
        // gatsby-remark-relative-images-v2 must
        // go before gatsby-remark-images
        {
          resolve: `gatsby-remark-relative-images-v2`,
        },
        {
          resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
          options: {
            maxWidth: 590,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ```

Comment: Ferran Buireu, is it possible to use a url string or a relative path? The issue only occurs when the markdown string value is a url not a relative path. I'll have a look at your adjustments later today. And thank you!

Comment: You can't use a URL if you want to use `gatsby-image`. For a standard `img` tag, it may work but Gatsby needs to parse the assets to apply its transformers and sharps so the image needs to be local.

Comment: I think i could do the conditional check in the component, check if it is a relative path or if it is a url, then do the template string accordingly.

Comment: Well in that case the solution is completely up to you. If you can download the assets to store it locally it could be a solution, yes.